# Symfony self-update failing

Tags: symfony, symfony4

When I do `symfony self-update` I get the following error - how can I solve it?

```
Backup failed, rename D:\SERVER\Symfony\symfony.exe C:\Users\FairyWilbury\.symfo
ny\autoupdate\2019-07-19_14-57-14-79024bb-old: The system cannot move the file t
o a different disk drive.. Canceling upgrade.
```

UPD.
I have just realized that the latest symfony version seems to be 4.3 with 4.4 due to release in November https://symfony.com/roadmap/4.4
Yet whenever I run `symfony new --full %projectName%` it suggests I should update to 4.6 (and then fails to update as described above). Screenshot of the command line: [image: s]What can this problem be?

Comment: If the The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive... you may solve it if you move the file to the same disk first (manually (even in console)) :O This is the full output?

Comment: That's all the output. Why is this happening though? Shouldn't it be able to update the system even if the symfony.exe is not on the drive C:?

Comment: Not sure, just tip, but may the php does not have access to the disk... local env?

Comment: Do you know how I can test that theory? :)

Comment: I have ran php -i, the homedrive in the environment is C:, but the session data is stored on D:. Would I be right to assume that it means it does have access to both?

Comment: I have also tried 'php -r mkdir([...]);' in the command on both C: and D: - it works. I suppose that means it can access both drives.

Comment: Weird... You follow the symfony doc? This is the first time, when you use this command (symfony self-update) to update 4.x? What the original version of symfony, so that, what you try update?

Comment: I am updating to 4.6.1 (that's what it offers me) and current version is 4.2.10 It's the first time I run self-update.

Comment: Hey, check my answer and follow the linked symfony docs. If that not solve the problem, or you want something different (what is this `self-update`), link me some documentation about this (anything, what you find).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you're mixing up *Symfony Local Web Server* and the *Symfony PHP framework*. You can use the web server, which is a single executable command line developer tool, to start a new Symfony-based project or start a local server that makes your web application available for testing and debugging while you develop it. The framework, on the other hand, is the code base you build web application on.

When you run

```
symfony self-update
```

from the command line, you (try to) update the web server, not the framework.

The latest version of the web server, at the time of writing, is 4.12.10, while the framework is at 5.0.5 (or 4.4.5), so, as you can see, they're completely independent from each other.

Back to the original problem, and I was struggling with this as well, the catch is that we both use Windows and installed the web server (symfony.exe) to a folder in drive D: (in your case it's D:\SERVER\Symfony). While it's running, it stores config and other files in a ".symfony" directory in the folder of your Windows user account (C:\Users\FairyWilbury). And during the self-update process, that's where it tries to move the original symfony.exe file. For some unknown reason, it cannot do that between different drives, not even in an Administrator-privileged command line window.

Strange, as it is, the only solution I found was the following.

1. I created a TEMP folder on drive C:
2. Copied symfony.exe from its folder on drive D: to C:\TEMP
3. Opened up command line, and switched the current dir to C:\TEMP
4. Ran `symfony self-update` -- this time it went smoothly
5. Closed the command line window
6. Moved the new symfony.exe file from C:\TEMP to the folder on drive D:
7. Removed C:\TEMP folder

I know it's a bit cumbersome, but we have to consider that Windows is not the most popular development platform for PHP applications. ;)

Comment: Yes this works fine, thanks. The only issue I found is when you are in `C:/TEMP` folder you have to run the symfony.exe that is in this folder. If not it will use the global symfony variable and the problem would be the same.

Run the command like this: `.\symfony.exe self:update`

Answer (score 1):

This command helped me to update `symfony` binary:

```
sudo symfony self-update
```

Comment: That was the tip I needed. A permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

okay, look, in this case, I dont really find anything about this `symfony self-update` stuff, so...

In the version title the third part (so the 1 in 4.6.1) is a patch, what that only contains bug fixes, so you need the latest minor version first `4.6.0`.

Basicly you need follow this doc:
[symfony/doc/upgrade_patch.html](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_patch.html)

And, as it starts above, first you need follow this doc (attentively):
[symfony/doc/4.2/upgrade_minor.html](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/setup/upgrade_minor.html)

This upgrade_minor.html writes: `The composer.json file is configured to allow Symfony packages to be upgraded to patch versions.`, so ...

Comment: I have added new details to the original questions as I've just realized that there is no version 4.6 despite me being prompted for update.